# Is there a way in Asp.Net to communicate with a background thread running Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Scenario

1. Server has to process a set of reports, each containing *n* no of employees
2. The UI takes in a bunch of inputs and fires the call to process the reports
3. The process call on the server is queued to a background thread using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`
4. The function running in this background thread uses `Parallel.ForEach` to parallelize the reports processing logic
5. The UI basically shows a simple grid containing list of reports and each report has a *status* which is receiving updates from the server via SignalR

The challenge here is that we need the ability to cancel each report from the UI. But the reports processing logic is inside a `Parallel.ForEach`. I did see documentation regarding `CancellationToken`, but that will break the entire loop. What I am looking for is a way to communicate with each task running within `Parallel.ForEach` and indicating if it has to be cancelled when a request to cancel comes from the UI.

Is that even possible ? Or if there is any other approach ?

Comment: sure, if you register reports in some object like dictionary and during process your processor will check in that dictionary for a token to stop processing... Then, when you send cancel command, you check that against certain job, if exists, certain key for each report, and you set cancel flag..... Or, you can create producer-consumer setup with multiple consumers, each started using `Task.Run`, then use tokens individually.

Comment: Why do you think the use of a `CancellationToken` will "break the entire loop"?

Comment: @Enigmativity I see that if we have one CancellationToken which is sent into this loop, and throw an exception it will break the loop, isn't it ?

Comment: @user11944367 - a `CancellationToken` doesn't have to throw. You can just inspect the `.IsCancellationRequested` property to see if you need to cancel the operations.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops) regarding handling exceptions in a parallel loop. You can in fact build it out so that an exception thrown can be caught inside the loop iteration, and you have some control over which are caught when.

Then, build a data structure that holds a Task, a CancellationTokenSource, and some way to identify the report it's bound to. Set up each task in that structure with it's own CancellationTokenSource, set up a cancellation token for the task based on that source, and set up your background worker to iterate over a collection of that structure and start the task from there. Then if you need to cancel, you can access the containing structure in the collection by ID, flip the token source to cancelled using the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method, and the task will stop and throw an OperationCanceledException, which you can catch in the loop iteration and ignore.

Comment: I see a merit in this approach. Will try out